# Como puedo Cambiar tamaño al adjuntar la imagen en asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Buenos dias compañeros quisiera que me puedan ayudar estoy realizando una pagina donde el usuario puede seleccionar dos imagenes y esas imagenes se guardan en una tabla sql server . Pues ahora tengo un problema cuando son excesivamente pesan bastante la imagen me sale el siguiente error .

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

yo ya lo he subido todo la cantidad en el webconfig para que no ocurra pero no se si habra una manera de cuando adjunte una imagen , se redusca la cantidad de peso de las imagenes..

Este es ee codigo en mi WebConfig.

```
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
        <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" executionTimeout="500000" maxRequestLength="999999999"/>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>

      </system.web>
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Ws_MostrarDatosPorUsuarioSoap" maxBufferSize="999999980"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="999999980" />
        <binding name="ExtendedMaxSize" maxBufferSize="999999980" maxReceivedMessageSize="999999980" />
        <binding name="Ws_BuscarClienteSoap" maxBufferSize="999999980"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="999999980" />
        <binding name="Ws_RespuestaNoSoap" maxBufferSize="999999980"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="999999980" />
        <binding name="Ws_ListaVerificacionSoap" maxBufferSize="999999980"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="999999980" />
        <binding name="Ws_IngresoSoap" maxBufferSize="999999980" maxReceivedMessageSize="999999980" />
        <binding name="Ws_CambioEstadoSoap" maxBufferSize="999999980" maxReceivedMessageSize="999999980"/>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

y este es el codigo donde guardo la imagenes:

```
 protected void btnGuardarImagen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
      int fileLength1 = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
                byte[] imageBytes1 = new byte[fileLength1];
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(imageBytes1, 0, fileLength1);

                int fileLength2 = FileUpload2.PostedFile.ContentLength;
                byte[] imageBytes2 = new byte[fileLength2];
                FileUpload2.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(imageBytes2, 0, fileLength2);

                int fileLength3 = FileUpload3.PostedFile.ContentLength;
                byte[] imageBytes3 = new byte[fileLength3];
                FileUpload3.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(imageBytes3, 0, fileLength3);


                Ws_CambioEstado.Ws_CambioEstadoSoapClient CambioEstados = new Ws_CambioEstado.Ws_CambioEstadoSoapClient();

                CambioEstados.CambioEstado(imageBytes1, imageBytes2, imageBytes3);
}
```

Comment: lamentablemente, a menos que reduzcas la resolución de la imagen, no se podrá. Por cierto, es más preferible que guardes en otros sitios o cualquier otra alternativa que no sea guardar la imagen en base de datos. podrías guardar la imagen directamente en el servidor o buscar alguna API que te ayude con eso, por ejemplo, puedes guardarlas en Imgur y sólo recuperas el link de la imagen, o usa el google picker.

Comment: @L.Ronquillo lo solucione y si se pudo todo se puede en esta vida Hermano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas Lo solucione este que le sirva mis amigos no importa la resolucion que tengan todos los celulares siempre le va reducir el peso al que yo le coloque:

Primero tienen que crear una clase a esta clase llamaremos

```
 public class VariablesGlobales
    {
        public static Byte[] Imagen1 { get; set; }
        public static Byte[] Imagen2 { get; set; }
        public static Byte[] Imagen3 { get; set; }

        public static int controlMessage { get; set; }

    }



#region Imagen
public byte[] Imagen(HttpPostedFile file)
{
    // Nombre de la imagen
    string nombre = file.FileName.Substring(
      0, file.FileName.LastIndexOf("."));
    // Extensión del archivo
    string ext = nombre.Substring(nombre.LastIndexOf(".") + 1);
    // Tipo de contenido
    string contentType = file.ContentType;
    // Imagen convertida a arreglo de bytes
    byte[] imagen = new byte[file.InputStream.Length];
    file.InputStream.Read(imagen, 0, imagen.Length);

    return imagen;
}
private void capturarImagenes()
{
    byte[] FotoDomicilio = VariablesGlobales.Imagen1;
    byte[] FotoDomicilio2 = VariablesGlobales.Imagen2;
    byte[] FotoDomicilio3 = VariablesGlobales.Imagen3;


    if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength != 0)
    {
        FotoDomicilio = ResizeImageFile(Imagen(FileUpload1.PostedFile), 700);
    }
    if (FileUpload2.PostedFile.ContentLength != 0)
    {
        FotoDomicilio2 = ResizeImageFile(Imagen(FileUpload2.PostedFile), 700);
    }
    if (FileUpload3.PostedFile.ContentLength != 0)
    {
        FotoDomicilio3 = ResizeImageFile(Imagen(FileUpload3.PostedFile), 700);
    }

    //-----------------------Registar en la Variable Global las Imagenes-----------------
    VariablesGlobales.Imagen1 = FotoDomicilio;
   VariablesGlobales.Imagen2 = FotoDomicilio2;
    VariablesGlobales.Imagen3 = FotoDomicilio3;

}

private static byte[] ResizeImageFile(byte[] imageFile, int targetSize)
{
    using (System.Drawing.Image oldImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(imageFile)))
    {
        Size newSize = CalculateDimensions(oldImage.Size, targetSize);
        using (Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(newSize.Width, newSize.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb))
        {
            using (Graphics canvas = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
            {
                canvas.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                canvas.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                canvas.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                canvas.DrawImage(oldImage, new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), newSize));
                MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
                newImage.Save(m, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                return m.GetBuffer();
            }
        }
    }
}
private static Size CalculateDimensions(Size oldSize, int targetSize)
{
    Size newSize = new Size();

    if (oldSize.Height > oldSize.Width)
    {
        newSize.Width = (int)(oldSize.Width * ((float)targetSize / (float)oldSize.Height));
        newSize.Height = targetSize;
    }

    else
    {
        newSize.Width = targetSize;
        newSize.Height = (int)(oldSize.Height * ((float)targetSize / (float)oldSize.Width));
    }

    return newSize;
}
#endregion
```

y solo ingresamos la variable que reducimos y Listo.

Comment: woooow, pues sin duda, estoy sorprendido, hasta donde yo sabía, no había forma, puedes mostrarme cómo se ve la imagen una vez pasada por tu código? me acabas de llenar de intriga.

Comment: Me surgió una duda: el error original se debió a que se había excedido el tamaño máximo del request. El código que se muestra reduce el tamaño de la imagen una vez recibida, pero si la imagen excede el tamaño máximo del request de cualquier modo no podría ser procesada, ya que no llegaría al servidor. Es decir, este código nos permite reducir el tamaño en la BD, pero no resolver el problema del request size excedido.